# C# - Can a Method Parameter be a Class of variable type?

Tags: c#

I have a static method whose internal code is capable of working with multiple different classes.  However I am unsure how to get the classes into the method at run time.

For example lets say I have ClassA and ClassB

My method can work with either of these classes and so I want the parameters to look something like.

```
public static void MyMethod(Object obj)
{
    //...obj is either ClassA or ClassB
    //...do work on variable class
}
```

But I keep getting an invalid argument message when I try either

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
MyMethod(a);

ClassB b = new ClassB();
MyMethod(b)
```

Is it even possible to have a parameter who's Type is unknown until runtime?

If so how do I do this?

If not, how can a method that performs some function on many classes by utilised in this way, without repeating the method code in every class?

EDIT - I have edited the above as my code DOES indeed pass in an instance of a class, and not just the class name.  However I still do get the Invalid argument message.

Comment: do you mean instances of `ClassA` or `Type` instance? You can't pass class name as itself like this `MyMethod(ClassA)`

Comment: BTW, you might want to consider having the two types implement a common interface, and make it `MyMethod(ISomeInterface obj)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ClassA` is a type name, then that syntax is not valid; you must either pass in an *instance* of the type, or the `Type` of the type:

```
MyMethod(new ClassA());
```

or

```
MyMethod(typeof(ClassA));
```

For the latter case, you could also consider refactoring to use generics:

```
MyMethod<ClassA>();
```

> Is it even possible to have a parameter who's Type is unknown until runtime?

Absolutely; `object` would be fine, but you need to give that parameter a valid value.

Comment: Isn't it a huge LSP violation with `static void MyMethod(Object obj)` and then casting `obj` to `ClassA` or `ClassB`?

Comment: @IlyaIvanov nobody said anything about casting to those, specifically. An interface might be the ideal solution, but it really depends on the full context, which we don't really know.

Comment: ok, I don't give objections to your answer. I've just wondered regarding assumption `obj is either ClassA or ClassB` in question and how method overloading fits to this need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an instance (object) of the class.  Try:

```
MyMethod(new ClassA());
MyMethod(new ClassB());
```

I would suggest `overloading` MyMethod, such as:

```
public void MyMethod(ClassA a) { ... }
punlic void MyMethod(ClassB b) { ... }
```

Comment: How is having multiple overloads (one per parameter type) any better than repeating the method in each class?  Both seem to include a lot of repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a type, not an instance of a type.

Consider this instead:-

```
var test = new ClassA();
MyMethod(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should overload `MyMethod` as suggested by Richard.

If you still want to use just one method definition, you could use something like:

```
public static void UnknownArgumentsMethod2(params object[] list)
{
    foreach (object o in list)
    {
        if (o.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is an integer: " + (int)o);
        }
        else if (o.GetType() == typeof(ClassA))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is an object of ClassA");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If ClassA and ClassB have same function signatures, consider using Interfaces. If implementations are same as well, implement them in base abstract class and override them in inherited classes if required.

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    void MethodX();
}

abstract class ClassBase: IMyInterface
{
    public virtual void MethodX()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MethodX from base class");
    }
}

// this will use base class implementation of MethodX
class ClassA : ClassBase
{
}

class ClassB : Classbase
{
    public void MethodX()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("MethodX from ClassB");
    }
}


class Foo
{
    public void MyMethod(IMyInterface obj)
    {
        obj.MethodX();
    }
}



Foo f = new Foo();

IMyInterface ca = new ClassA();
f.MyMethod(ca);  // This Print MethodX from ClassA, in this case BaseClass

IMyInterface cb = new ClassB();
f.MyMethod(cb);  // This Print MethodX from ClassB
```

Comment: I don't see how an Interface helps here.  As an Interface includes no implementations, I'd have to repeat he code in every class that uses the Interface.  Repetition of code is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error was here -

```
public static void MyMethod(Object obj)
```

Once I changed the parameter as follows:

```
public static void MyMethod(object obj)
```

it worked fine :)

Comment: I just came across this answer. `Object` and `object` are the same thing: `System.Object`. Those two lines are exactly the same!